# Local navigation with additional rescrictions

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

my goal is to navigate a robot (locally - in odometry frame) using one laser scanner. Moreover I will have some additional restrictions - areas where the robot should not go. I found here two related questions (please let me know if I missed any):

- [Custom CostMap Values](http://answers.ros.org/question/12569/custom-costmap-values/)
- [Update costmap_2d with user defined no go zones](http://answers.ros.org/question/52652/update-costmap_2d-with-user-defined-no-go-zones/)

Generating artificial sensor data seems to be sufficient but bit hacky in my opinion... Is this something which might be solved using [layered costmaps](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/New-navigation-SIG-hydro-release-layered-costmaps-td4020016.html)? Or is there any other good approach? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66083/local-navigation-with-additional-rescrictions/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the author of the first question and layered costmaps, yes, layered costmaps are a good solution for the problem.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-06-27**:
Ok, thanks for hint. Is there any documentation or examples how to work with layered costmaps?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-06-27**:
This is the best I can point you to at the moment: http://ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d/hydro

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's an example layering a static map on top of your usual obstacle + inflation local costmap

`local_costmap_params.yaml`

```
local_costmap:
  plugins: 
    - {name: static_map, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: obstacles, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: inflation, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  transform_tolerance: 5.0
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0

  obstacles:
      observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
      laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

More details on the types of layers supported can be found here:

- https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/costmap_2d/src/costmap_2d_ros.cpp#L279
- https://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Configuring%20Layered%20Costmaps

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-04-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1